# Excel: sum odd/even rows only in R1C1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I sum cells in odd/even rows only using R1C1?

I tried to follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136738) example. So suppose you have a table like this:

```
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
```

Then value `6` is the result of a formula:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(RC[-1]:R[2]C[-1]),2)=1,RC[-1]:R[2]C[-1],0))
```

Even though it should give `4`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter it as an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will produce the desired result.

Comment: damn it... it sure will. I always forget about it. thanks for help

Comment: You're welcome. It's easier to catch when the formula fails entirely :).

Comment: @DougGlancy, you're right, my idea didn't work. I retract that comment.